# jsp compile errors using jdk1.8

Tags: jsp

I get the following error message when Tomcat 6.035 tries to compile my jsp file:

> An error occurred at line: 222 in the jsp file: /search_results.jsp
>   The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

```
219: </td></tr>
220: 
221: <% strPhone = rs.getString("Phone");
222: if(strPhone.contains("-") || strPhone.contains("(") || strPhone.contains(")"))
```

I recently switched to jdk8u40 and on googling the problem, I find that some default interfaces present in earlier jdk versions are not supported in jdk1.8.
The standard solutions being offered are to switch back to jdk1.7 or reinstall the jre1.8.
I would like to know what code construct I can use for .contains(...) which is compatible with jdk1.8.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an Eclipse bug. Try to update your IDE.

Comment: I do not use Eclipse. I compile my classes the old fashioned way using textpad or from dos.

Comment: Then try with an up-to-date compiler :)

Comment: Tomcat 6.035 is a stand alone server and servlet/jsp container which converts jsp's to a .java file and compiles same.

Comment: are compilerSourceVM and compilerTargetVM set to 1.8 in tomcat/conf/web.xml ?